# iVar is not deallocated using ARC

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

I have a `UIScrollView` declared as an iVar in the implementation file of a class that uses ARC:

```
@interface RecipeBrowserViewController ()
{
    UIScrollView *tempScrollView;
}
```

This is necessary because during execution I need to sometimes add the `UIScrollView` to my view, and other times remove that same `UIScrollView`:

```
if (someTest) 
{
    tempScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    tempScrollView.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview: tempScrollView];
}
else 
{       
    [tempScrollView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

My expectation was that the `tempScrollView` would be deallocated once it's removed from the `superview`, but this is not the case. Presumably, because the iVar is still referencing it?

Adding `tempScrollView = nil` after removing it from the `superview` clears this up, but I'm not sure what the correct approach is. Am I supposed to declare a `weak` iVar instead? Thus far I have only seen `weak` suggested for delegates or other two-way iVars that would otherwise lead to a strong reference cycle. Is this another place I should be using it?

Comment: You're supposed to set the ivar to nil in `- dealloc`.

Comment: @H2CO3 that's not necessary with ARC. You rarely have to even implement `dealloc`.

Comment: @CarlVeazey you have to implement `- dealloc` even with ARC. You just don't call `[super dealloc];`.

Comment: @H2CO3 Perhaps I'm missing something, but the Apple release notes and my experience suggest that you only need to implement it if you need to e.g. release shared resources, but nothing is required for managing instance variables.

Comment: @H2CO3, Carl Veazey: The ARC spec confirms that strong instance variable references will be released automatically. http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#misc.special_methods.dealloc

Comment: @PeterHosey thank you for clarification. (I'll probably never learn all this though, since I don't use ARC).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding/removing the scroll view is a separate issue from ivar memory management. What you've got is correct, except that you should indeed set the ivar to nil when you're done with tempScrollView.

When you add View B (the scroll view) as a subview of View A (self.view), View A keeps a strong reference to (i.e. retains) View B. When you remove View B as a subview, View A removes its strong reference to (i.e. releases) View B. However, the ivar tempScrollView is strong, so the view controller (self) maintains a strong reference to the scrollview, and as you've seen, it's not deallocated. The way to remove that strong reference is to set the ivar to nil.

I'd add that in my opinion, you should use an @property for tempScrollView instead of using an ivar directly. With ARC it's not as much of an issue, but in general it's better to encapsulate memory management inside of property accessors, and it's the same number of lines of code at this point.

Comment: That's not entirely correct. Adding the view as a subview will add another reference to it- removing it from its superview takes a way that reference. Adding and removing subviews very much impacts memory management.

Comment: @Rickay, yes of course, my initial answer was a bit simplistic, and I've expanded it with a more thorough explanation.

Comment: Thanks. I need to review all of my code and apply the same logic. Having come to iOS post-ARC, and only now examining performance and memory management of my application, I am realizing ARC isn't an excuse to ignore memory altogether.

Comment: As for your comment on using a property - does this still apply if tempScrollView is not exposed to any other class?

Comment: Furthermore, if I use a property instead, would I no longer need to bother with the memory management?

Comment: @BenPackard: It doesn't really make any difference. Either way, you still have to throw away the scroll view when you no longer want it.

Comment: @PeterHosey is right. I probably just made things more confusing with my comment about properties. I consider using them good practice, but in this case it's not going really going to make any difference. You will still need to nil out the property when you're done.